# Is that a number? C++ and via stringstream

Tags: c++, numbers, ifstream, stringstream

I am a beginner in StackOverflow and in C++, this is my first post.
The aim of this function is to get a line like:

### 1224435 1998-11-02 23:43:54 2514352842 00:01:22 01.25

callingNumber, dateOfCall, hourOfCall numberCalled durationOfTalk costOfTalk

and then input it in the correct variables. The string is abandoned in numbers.(School task)
I am looking for correct way to check if stringstream which is inputted into long or short, is a number. All help appreciated.
Here is what I mean:

```
void lineCutter(string nameOfFile,sortedList * & pHead)
{
        ifstream telephones(nameOfFile);
        stringstream converter;        
        string Bcontainer ;



        long numC;

        short dateY;
        short dateM;
        short dateD;

        short talkH;       
        short talkM;
        short talkS;

        long numG;

        short durationH;
        short durationM;
        short durationS;

        short costZ;
        short costG;


        if(telephones)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            cout<< "I'm in"<<endl;
            while(getline(telephones,Bcontainer))

            {   
                for(int i = 0; i<Bcontainer.size(); i++)
                {
                 if(Bcontainer[i] == 32)
                 {
                            counter++;
                 }
                }

                if(counter == 5)
                {

                    replace (Bcontainer.begin(), Bcontainer.end(), ':', ' ');
                    replace (Bcontainer.begin(), Bcontainer.end(), '.', ' ');
                    replace (Bcontainer.begin(), Bcontainer.end(), '-', ' ');


                    converter << Bcontainer ;


                    converter >> numC >> dateY >> dateM >> dateD >> talkH >> talkM >> talkS >> numG >> durationH >> durationM >> durationS >> costZ >> costG;


                   if( all vars are in correct format  )// Are they numbers?

                    pHead =  new sortedList { numC , dateY , dateM , dateD , talkH , talkM , talkS , numG , durationH , durationM , durationS , costZ , costG, pHead};
                   } //pHead is a head pointer of a single linked list


                 }

                  counter = 0;
            } 

            telefony.close();


        }
        else{
            cout<<"Cannot open."<<endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: A comprehensive answer covers quite a few things: Do we regard the input as potentially 'hostile'? (not formatted as expected). Do we have strict upper limits for phone numbers? For example, my international AU prefix mobile is "+61xxxxxxxxx", which omitting the `+`, requires a `long long` to (portably) hold. Can the call length or call cost ever reach 24 hours or $100 respectively?

Comment: Our talk may talk as much as we want to, but, we have to respect 60 rule (60 sec, 60 min etc, cannot make 61 sec), the number has to be longer than 9, but less than 15 digits (no + or #), the cost is normal, costZ is for "bigger" currency, as costG is for smaller. For example, "04.10" (in column cost) would be 04 dollars, and 10 cents. Yes, we can have 100 dollars or even more.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to go with boost's lexical casts like this:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(123);  // converting number to a string
    std::cout << s << '\n';
    double d = boost::lexical_cast<double>(s); // convert to number from string
    std::cout << d << '\n';



    try
    {
        double d = boost::lexical_cast<double>("not a number");   /// is not a number and exception is thrown
    }
    catch (const boost::bad_lexical_cast &e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    try
    {
        short d = boost::lexical_cast<short>("123456789012345678901234567890");   /// type to small to hold number
    }
    catch (const boost::bad_lexical_cast &e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Boost is a well tested library with little surprises. If you try to convert a string which cannot be represented by the type you cast to, it thorws an exception (which is by the way also configurable with policies).

**EDIT** 
If using the boost library is to complicated, you may check if the streaming to the variables worked. For this consider the following example:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream s("1 2 3 4 5 6");
    int val1;
    int val2;
    int val3;
    int val4;
    int val5;
    int val6;

    s >> val1 >> val2 >> val3 >> val4 >> val5 >> val6;

    if (s.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "failed to read value" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << val1 << " " << val2 << " " << val3 << " " << val4 << " " << val5 << " " << val6 << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If one of the values in the stringstream cannot be converted the failure message is printed.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know if I understand correctly,  You are using string to hold number?
In this task it is forbidden, I could only use a string  to get a line, but not to hold numbers. I know that it is stupid but I can do nothing about that ;)

Comment: You have BContainer which is a string. Instead of streaming it to the variables, tokanize it and use boost lexical cast.

Comment: I tried all things, except bridge, as @BrettHale said, it is to hard for me.
When trying with failbit, the program stopped working after fail place (like "23423fdsgg"), with flags something different, it was failing because during streaming into var, it wasn't  "55534134", but "55534134 " because of space separating each number. I tried to add exceptions, via ASCII or char, streaming into help var, removing spaces, and then checking, everything failed. Any other propositions? Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Prior to C++11 failing to read a numeric value from a inputstream would result in the `failbit` of the stream to be set and the value left unmodified. 
In C++11 and later the `failbit` of the stream will be set and the value will either be `0` if extraction of the value fails, or `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` or `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()` if the value is to big/small.

```
std::stringstream s("test");
long value;
s >> value;
if(s.fail()) 
  std::cout << "failed to read value" << std::endl;
else
  std::cout << "value is " << std::endl;
```

The output of the example will be:

```
failed to read value
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use boolean function:

```
bool isNumber(std::string value){
   int limit = value.size();
   for(int i=0; i<limit; i++){
      if(value[i]<48 or value[i]>59){
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: `if(value[i]<48 or value[i]>59)` looks odd, why don't you use `if (isdigit(value[i]))`?